# Need my UITextField to have a straight edge border

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I am working on an iOS application where I am using UITextField's inside a custom UITableViewCell.  However, the problem I am having is that my UITextFields all have round corners, which I do not want.  I would like straight edge corners for all of my UITextFields, and all I am coming across in researching this is how to give round edges to the UITextFields.  I have tried adding a border style of type "Line"

Here is my code where I create my UITextField's to be used within my UITableView:

```
    _dataField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(28.5, 15, 80, 40)];
    [_dataField setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:28]];
    [_dataField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
    [[_dataField layer] setCornerRadius:8.0f];
    [[_dataField layer] setMasksToBounds:8.0f];
    [[_dataField layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
    [[_dataField layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
```

What is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're setting the corner radius in the 4th line of code on the fields layer. Comment that out and try again.

Comment: You have no idea how stupid I feel.

Comment: I'm glad this received an answer, but it is probably not going to be useful for other readers. I will try to close it as a "typo" question (official close reason: "It's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want rounded corners remove the line:

```
[[_dataField layer] setCornerRadius:8.0f];
```